# How to get the gradient color from top right to bottom left corner

Tags: html, css

I have trying to get the `css` gradient as like in the below bootstrap icon.

[image: logo]

I just want two solutions from this code.

> 1.)How to make gradient color as like in icon(From top right to bottom left)?
>
> 2.)Vertical alignment of text within div(Possibility without using flex property)

Thanks in advance :)

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
  border-radius:4px;
}
div p{
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:42px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>
   b
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use `to top right` keyword for directing gradient to move from bottom left corner to top right corner.
   `background: linear-gradient(to top right, #2F2727, #1a82f7);`
2. Use `line-height` equal to `height`.

More Information about css gradient is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
  border-radius:4px;
}
div p{
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:42px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>
   b
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine. And I'll change the color code. Thank you Usman.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
div {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **radial gradient positioning** - `top right` for this, like:

```
background: linear-gradient(
            to top right, 
            #0F0437, #612D50
);
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px 70px;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to top right, 
      #0F0437, #612D50
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="box">B</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `to top right` for a diagonal angle (alternatively `45deg`), and `line-height` equivalent to your `height` value to vertically center the letter.

Here it is with colors sampled from your image:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #080135 0%, #612d50 100%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>B</div>
```